# Swift: Reduce TextInput View after Send

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a chat application and am implementing `isScrollEnabled` when the `numberOfLines` exceed a certain number. I do this by fixing `heightConstraint` and enabling `isScrollEnabled`. After the text is sent, I need the textInput View to return to its original height. Right now, the height remains as of the previous height that was set.

```
//At the inputAccessoryView
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

extension InputAccessoryView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let layoutManager:NSLayoutManager = textView.layoutManager
        let numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
        var numberOfLines = 0
        var index = 0
        var lineRange:NSRange = NSRange()

        while (index < numberOfGlyphs) {
            layoutManager.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
            index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
            numberOfLines = numberOfLines + 1
        }

        let height = self.frame.height
        heightConstraint = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)

        if numberOfLines > permissibleNumberOfLines {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true         
            heightConstraint.isActive = true

        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            heightConstraint.isActive = false
        }
    }
}

//When the sendButton is tapped at the ViewController
@objc func sendButtonDidTap() {
    //All the update Database thingy

    let constraint = chatInputAccessoryView.heightConstraint
    constraint?.isActive = false
}
```

I have also attempted to obtain the defaultHeightConstant, but that would permanently set the heightConstraint. Any advice how best to do this?

Comment: Make sure two different object is not creating for heightConstraint.

Or directly set you constrains chatInputAccessoryView.heightConstraint.isActive = false

Comment: @PaulMarshal that I'm sure. Both objects are not creating for heightConstraint

Comment: did you tried to call textView.setneedslayout?

Comment: @tereks No, I did not. Where should I call this? I've attempted to call it after the `sendButtonDidTap` and also after setting `isScrollEnabled`. Both didn't do any changes

Comment: After constraint.isActive changes

Comment: @tereks tried. It did not change anything

Comment: HAve you tries setting chatInputAccessoryView.heightConstraint.constant = defaultValue before deactivating?

Comment: @tereks also tried. The trouble is that when I set `heightConstraint.constant = defaultValue`, it permanently fixes it. If I type a text with more than 3 lines, the `heightConstraint` will not adjust accordingly